# webcam problem in ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, drivers, webcam

Today i bought a WEBCAM but it didn't work with my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

webcam model is = `ZENITH`

Os : `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS`

i tried `cheese` but it says `No Device found`.
[image]

These are the results of `lsusb` in terminal :

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bc2:2321 Seagate RSS LLC Expansion Portable
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1b3f:2008 Generalplus Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1a2c:2124 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 031: ID 0ac8:307b Z-Star Microelectronics Corp. USB 1.1 Webcam
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I think this line is for webcam :

```
Bus 001 Device 031: ID 0ac8:307b Z-Star Microelectronics Corp. USB 1.1 Webcam
```

I tried Online webcam testing tools and webcam is working in this case.

How can i solve this issue ?

EDIT :

in here : http://www.ideasonboard.org/uvc/ i couldn't find this device in list.

Comment: Have a poke around here and see if this helps.
It is the best generic info I can find outside of this site, which may help.

http://www.linuxintro.org/wiki/Set_up_a_Webcam_with_Linux

Comment: install guvcview and see if you get the same issue. `sudo apt install guvcview`

Comment: @ldias `guvcview` is working. but `kazam` `obs-studio` `cheese` can not detect webcam

Comment: @abasnikzad does the webcam work with skype, zoom, etc?

Comment: @ldias in skype webcam is a black screen only